# Data compression on Android (other than java.util.zip ?)

Tags: android, compression, zip

I have a lot of data (text format) to send from a device. It obviously means that I should compress it. But my question is whether there are any ways of doing it other than by zip algorithm ([like this](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29)). The reason I am asking this question is over [here](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/software-reviews/7-zip-vs-winzip-vs-winrar/) - for a text file i.e. 7-zip is twice (!) better than zip. Which is a significant gain. And maybe there are even better algorithms.

So are there any effective ways of data compression (better than zip) available for Android?

Comment: Twice as good... well that is certainly one issue. Different compression algorithms are better than others especially with certain kinds of data compression, but this is not the only consideration. Standardization, patent encumbrances and speed are very important.

Comment: A quick search seems to indicate that your easy choices are Zip and Gzip.

Comment: zip and gzip use the same compression algorithm, just different headers and trailers than zip.  So you might save a few bytes on headers and trailers by using the gzip format, and a few more bytes if you use the zlib format.  But nothing substantial like you'd get with more advanced compression algorithms that require more time and more memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to compile another library into your code, since I doubt that compression algorithms other than [zlib](http://zlib.net/) are available as part of the standard libraries on the Android.

The 7-zip algorithm you refer to is actually called LZMA, which you can get in library form in the [LZMA SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html).  The source code is available in Java as well as C.  If you can link C code into your application, that would be preferable for speed.

Since there's no such thing as a free lunch, the speed is important.  LZMA will require much more memory and much more execution time to achieve the improved compression.  You should experiment with LZMA and zlib on your data to see where you would like the tradeoff to fall between execution time and compression, both to choose a package and to pick compression levels within a package.

If you find that you'd like to go the other way, to less compression and even higher speed than zlib, you can look at [lz4](http://code.google.com/p/lz4/).

Answer (score -1):

Your question is too general.

You can use any library, as long as it is in Java or C/C++ (via the NDK). If you don't want to use external libraries, you have to stick to what's in the SDK. Depending on how you are sending the data, there might be standard ways to do this. For example, HTTP uses gzip and has the necessary headers already defined.

In short, test different things with your expected data format and size, find the best one and integrate it in your app.

Comment: data is being sent over custom protocol, so I won't use HTTP. Could you please give me a hint on a good java compression lib? I've never really used any.

Comment: My either :) The JDK ones have been sufficient for me. Instead of just picking a random one, find a few and test them against your data.